# Strange MongoDB $setIntersection behaviour

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to query a match between records in my db based on certain tags. The match would be calculated based on a formula and the intersection of the tags. Now, even querying the intersection doesn't work...always. Sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't. In my example, if I change the displayName attribute to something else (add or remove one character, the query works. In its current state (for demo purposes) it doesn't as it does not deliver the one intersection match for the last doc with id 3.

https://mongoplayground.net/p/KAYPoV29RFO

That's my query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "_id": "1"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      from: "collection",
      let: {
        "criteria": "$tags"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $project: {
            "match": {
              $setIntersection: [
                "$tags",
                "$$criteria"
              ]
            },
            
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "result"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "tags": 0
    }
  },
  
])
```

Here is the example data (simplified):

```
[
  { "_id": "1", "tags": [{ "_id": "a", "displayName": "a", "level": 1}, {"_id": "b", "displayName": "b", "level": 2}, {"_id": "c", "displayName": "c", "level": 3}]},
  {"_id": "2", "tags": [{"_id": "a", "displayName": "a", "level": 1}, {"_id": "b", "displayName": "b", "level": 2}]},
  {"_id": "3", "tags": [{"_id": "a", "displayName": "a", "level": 1}, {"_id": "d", "displayName": "d", "level": 4}]}
]
```

and the result as it is: (expected is three matches for id 1, 2 matches for id 2 and one for the last id. However, the last result has 0 elements in the intersection result. Again, when i change "displayName" to "displayNam" or "displayNames" (obviously in all docs), it give the correct result...

```
[{
  "_id": "1", "result": [
    {"_id": "1", "match": [{"_id": "a", "displayName": "a", "level": 1}, {"_id": "b", "displayName": "b", "level": 2},{"_id": "c","displayName": "c","level": 3}]},
    {"_id": "2", "match": [{"_id": "a", "displayName": "a", "level": 1}, {"_id": "b", "displayName": "b", "level": 2}]},
    {"_id": "3","match": [*here should be the match to _id: "a", but it's not (always) there*]}
  ]
}]
```

Does anyone have an idea what I am missing here?

Comment: I would speculate that this might have to do with [object comparison semantics](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/bson-type-comparison-order/#objects). Specifically key-value pairs are '_compare[d] **in the order that they appear** within the BSON object_'. The playground itself has some problems with preserving field ordering as noted in [issue 153](https://github.com/feliixx/mongoplayground/issues/153#issuecomment-1314357341)

Comment: Hmm. But then it wouldn’t explain why it behaves the same in Studio3T and an actual mongo server on my computer. Also it wouldn’t explain, that it definitely works every time when I change displayName to displayNames or displayNam…don’t you think?

Comment: I think it might actually explain the behavior. Different tools/utilities use different drivers that have different ways for specifying ordering. If you simplify the `tags` down to a single field in the subdocument my guess is that it will be consistent every time. By the way, your playground link is showing the correct result for the `_id: 3` match for me at the moment

Comment: Yeah, it seems to work now. But it didn't, hence "sometimes". If you fancy, you can add your comment as an answer and I will accept it as it actually is true.